# FIWARE OPC-UA - iotagent4fiware/iotagent-opcua:latest NOT RUNNING

Tags: image, containers, fiware, opc-ua

I am going through the OPC UA Agent Tutorial
https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua/blob/master/docs/opc_ua_agent_tutorial.md

But after running the docker-compose one of the containers is not working and keeps giving errors. I have tried to delete every image and container and then run it again but still not working

```
***********************************************
```

WARNING: It is recommended to enable authentication for secure connection

---

INFO: IoT Agent running standalone

{"time":"2022-06-16T13:14:06.962Z","lvl":"ERROR","err":{"errno":-2,"syscall":"open","code":"ENOENT","path":"./conf/config.properties","message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './conf/config.properties'","name":"Error","constructor":"Error","stack":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './conf/config.properties'\n    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)\n    at readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)\n    at PropertiesReader.append (/opt/iotagent-opcua/node_modules/properties-reader/src/properties-reader.js:100:17)\n    at new PropertiesReader (/opt/iotagent-opcua/node_modules/properties-reader/src/properties-reader.js:16:9)\n    at propertiesReaderFactory (/opt/iotagent-opcua/node_modules/properties-reader/src/properties-reader-factory.js:6:11)\n    at Object.checkproperties (/opt/iotagent-opcua/iot_agent_modules/check_properties.js:4:26)\n    at Object. (/opt/iotagent-opcua/index.js:12:20)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)"},"msg":"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './conf/config.properties'"}

{"comp":"iotAgent-OPCUA","op":"Index","srv":"","subsrv":"","time":"2022-06-16T13:14:06.965Z","lvl":"ERROR","msg":"undefined"} `

Answer (score 1):

There was some issue for me in *docker-compose.yml*, volumes for iotagent4fiware/opcuacarsrv:latest were not correct. So, I have changed them according to the position of config.properties file location.

**Before:**
volumes:
- ./AGECONF:/opt/iotagent-opcua/conf

**After**
volumes:
- ./AGECONF/config:/opt/iotagent-opcua/conf/config